# Store password within app

Tags: java, android, password-protection

I am developing an app which sends email. I use [this](http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-send-e-mail-directly-from-android-application/) to send message, but it requires username and password of my gmail account. So, I need to store them in app. How to protect them from malefactors?

Comment: Use Shared Preferences. :) Data stored will be within application.

Comment: @AtulOHolic but I think even `SharedPreference`s are not secure...

Comment: That is not realy secure

Comment: You can open the shared preferences file just like any other text file on a rooted phone. So saving sensitive information in `SharedPreferences` is not encouraged.

Comment: How about storing in preferences in encrypted format. like cipher encryption. and when you need it in your application decrypt it.

Comment: Could you show me an example how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Don't store passwords use tokens like a session cookie on http. Sessions can been revoked server side by user actions without harming other sessions.

A password can been read out (even if it is encrypted you need to send it unencrypted to the server hopefully via TLS) and if the user uses that password on multiple sites the user will get a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the adequate answer, so I decided to get rid of storing password within my app. I just send request with necessary parameters to my server. The server gets these parameters, creates email and sends it to the recipient by using `PHPMailer` library. I used the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android) to send request to server. I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion but a little helpful. As other says `SharedPreferences` is fully secured but if we save data in SharedPreferences as encrypted format then it should applicable.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684130/encrypting-data-in-android) is a examples and also [MessageDigest](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest.html) will help you a little here.

Note: This question is directly proportional to security things, so I never recommend any of my answers. But it can be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for this but beware saving passwords is usually frowned upon even if highly encrypted.

Even in a PC app saving a password always warns you that the password is saved locally and is not secure from attacks.

Comment: This is the second answer in the past 10 minutes that suggested using shared preferences to store passwords.  Awful.

Comment: I agree that this is awful, which is why I mentioned that it is usually not the best idea to use it. Maybe I just worded my answer wrong.