# Android store user data securely

Tags: android, security

I want to store some sensitive data in Android app. 
I know I am able to store it in SharedPreference or put the data in sqlite. But if the user roots the app, then he will be able to get the data. 
I also know that I could encrypt the data and store it in the same places.
But, I do want to know if Android by default has some mechanism like that of iOS using keychain and store it in keychain.
I am not sure if somebody asked the same question. If yes please redirect me

Comment: there really isnt any "secure" place to store anything on a mobile device

Comment: You can use sqlcipher check this  https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher

Answer (score 1):

There is a library made by [Duncan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/474189/duncan) which you can find on GitHub ([JNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/JNCryptor)) and should be useful for you. This is compatible with the [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) project for iOS.

This may work for you on Android, or at least you can see how the code works and adapt it as necessary.

Take a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14704065/5080583) (Where I found the library) which is not the same as you're asking, but could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good idea is to use the Android Keystore to "secure" store your key and then use it to encrypt/decrypt your data.

It's always better to find a solution inside the Android framework without use a library for everything.

See this [link](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/trustzone/) for more infos.

If you want to use more sofisticated and "secure" way to encrypt/decrypt data you could think to store on a remote server your keys, but this depend on your application does.

**UPDATE**
NOTE you can secure store your data only using secure elements such as SIM card (see [this](http://nelenkov.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/using-sim-card-as-secure-element.html)). You can even use the [TEE](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/trustzone/) technology which is something more secure than filesystem but less secure than SIM to store secure object on your device. This technology is not available on all the devices.